# Cascade vs series?

Tags: control, control-system

Is there any difference between cascade combination and series combination in terms of control system? Or they both same?

Since in control system literature,sometimes at some places,we find the word cascade instead of series

Comment: Quote a reference and give full details.

Comment: Control systems usually employ a 'signal' transmission that is described by block diagrams where the signal is represented by a single arrow. In this context I believe you cannot distinguish between series and cascade. Block diagrams are notoriously unidirectional and do not implicitly account for loading effects. But if you use a 'power transfer' representation with two-ports, then you can distinguish between series and cascade. Two ports employs coupled variables - extensive and intensive, or effort and flow. And they implicity model load effects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the terms *cascade* and *series* mean the same thing when used to describe connections of systems.

From the perspective of signal flow, two systems connected in cascade fashion are connected such that the output of the first becomes the input of the second.

------>[System 1]----->[System 2]----->

The word *series* here makes sense because system 2 works on the original input signal **after** it has been modified by system 1.

The word *cascade* also makes sense, because each system contributes a **further** modification to the original input signal, and not just a direct change on the original input.